# JAXB: unmarshalling xml with multiple names for the same element

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, unmarshalling

I figure this will be easy for someone who really understands JAXB binding files...

### Basic Question

How do you configure JAXB to unmarshal multiple elements into the same class?

*Note: I want to avoid adding another dependency to my project (like MOXy). Ideally, this can be accomplished with annotations or a custom bindings file.*

### Background

I have an XML document that contains lots of variations of the same element--each with the exact same properties. Using my example below, all I care about is "Employees" but the XML specifies "directors, managers and staff." For our purposes, these are all subclasses of the same parent and we only need to work with the parent type (Employee) and our object model doesn't have or need instances of the subclasses.

**I want JAXB to bind any instance of `director, manager, or staff` elements into an `Employee` object.**

### Example

input:

```
<organization>
    <director>
        <fname>Dan</fname>
        <lname>Schman</lname>
    </director>    
    <manager>
        <fname>Joe</fname>
        <lname>Schmo</lname>
    </manager>    
    <staff>
        <fname>Ron</fname>
        <lname>Schwan</lname>
    </staff>    
    <staff>
        <fname>Jim</fname>
        <lname>Schwim</lname>
    </staff>    
    <staff>
        <fname>Jon</fname>
        <lname>Schwon</lname>
    </staff>    
</organization>
```

output:

After unmarshalling this example, I would end up with an `Organization` object with one property: `List<Employees> employees` where each employee only has a firstName and lastName.

(Note: each employee would be of type `Employee` NOT `Director/Manager/Staff`. Subclass information would be lost when unmarshalling. We also don't care about marshaling back out--we only need to create objects from XML)

Can this be done without extensions like MOXy? Can a custom bindings.xjb file save the day?

Comment: Hopefully @BlaiseDoughan will see your question, as he's been active on this site recently, and he knows his JAXB as well as anyone. [His blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/) is a worthwhile read.

Comment: that would be great. If so...I've got all kinds of upvotes and rep points with his name on them! ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This corresponds to a choice structure.  You could use an `@XmlElements` annotation for this use case:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="director", type=Employee.class),
    @XmlElement(name="manager", type=Employee.class)
})
List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

If you are starting from an XML schema the following will help:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: you, sir, are a genius! Worked like a charm!

Comment: As a follow-up: is there any easy way to preserve the original element name (like pass it as a property to the object being created)?

Comment: In JAXB you can have result wrapped in a `JAXBElement`. The ability to store that value in a property is something we've considering adding to MOXy.

Comment: @gmale - You could cast an official vote on the enhancement request here:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298125

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan is this also possible with the external mapping file? I tried <xml-elements> but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @BigBen - I see you have already figured this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15917708/383861 (I gave both your question and answer a +1).