# is it possible with JAXB to marshal two or more elements into one domain object field?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have two different XML structures I'd like to map to one domain object. I'm using MOXy's external binding support so I can choose which binding to use dynamically.

Here's my question. I have an XML structure like the one below:

```
<entity>
   <compoundID_one>foo</compoundID_one>
   <compoundID_two>bar</compoundID_two>
</entity>
```

I'd like to have a single `List<String>` field in my domain class which would contain 'foo' and 'bar'

I've tried this:

```
...
<java-attributes>
    <xml-elements>
        <xml-element java-attribute="idList" name="compoundID_one" />
        <xml-element java-attribute="idList" name="compoundID_two" />
    </xml-elements>
</java-attributes>
...
```

but I just get `null` for the field in the domain object. If I omit the `xml-elements` wrapper I only get one of the compoundID's in the list.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128191/jaxb-unmarshalling-xml-with-multiple-names-for-the-same-element/11128395#comment22671073_11128395) which seems to suggest this should work. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the binding XML wrong, it should be:

```
...
<java-attributes>
    <xml-elements java-attribute="idList">
        <xml-element name="compoundID_one" />
        <xml-element name="compoundID_two" />
    </xml-elements>
</java-attributes>
...
```

All works fine now.