# As I can relate in a single class, two different files with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I hope you can help me.

Currently I receive two files in `xml` format, I would like to know how you could relate those two files to the same class using `jaxb`.

**Company.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</records>
   <record>
      <id>4<id>
      <companyName>B</companyName>
      ......
   </record>
   <record>
      <id>7<id>
      <companyName>B</companyName>
        ......
   </record>
</records>
```

**Employees.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<records>         
     <record>
        <EmployeeName>AA</EmployeeName>
        <CompanyID>2</CompanyID>
     </record>
     <record>
        <EmployeeName>AB</EmployeeName>
        <CompanyID>2</CompanyID>
     </record>
 </records>
```

I would like to know how I can generate a class relating these fields id company

```
   public class Companys{
          private List<Company> list;
   }

   public class Company{
       private String companyName;
       private Integer id;
       .........
       //I need use JaxB --reference ID company
       private List<Employees> list; 
   }


   public class Employee{
        private String Name;
        private Integer idCompany;
        .......................
   }
```

Comment: Discusses many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128191/jaxb-unmarshalling-xml-with-multiple-names-for-the-same-element

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map.

```
public class Companies{
    private Map<Integer, Company> map = new HashMap<>();

    void put(Integer id, Company company) {
        map.put(id, company);
    }

    Company get(Integer id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }
}
```

Once you have your list of employees, you can then iterate through them and apply them onto the Companies map.

```
Company company = companies.get(employee.getIdCompany());
company.addEmployee(employee);
```

Alternatively, you can create a method inside companies called `addEmployee`

```
void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    companies.get(employee.getIdCompany()).addEmployee(employee);
}
```